# simple python syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement

```
class InterpolatedArray(object):

  """An array-like object that provides
  interpolated values between set points."""

  def __init__(self, points):
    self.points = sorted(points)

  def __getitem__(self, x):
    if x > self.points[-1][0]:
      return self.points[-1][1] + (x - self.points[-1][0]) * float((self.points[-1][1] - self.points[-2][1]) / (self.points[-1][0] - self.points[-2][0]))
    elif x < self.points[0][0]: 
      return self.points[0][1] + (x - self.points[0][0]) * float(self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1] / (self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0])
    else:
      lower_point, upper_point = self._GetBoundingPoints(x)
      return self._Interpolate(x, lower_point, upper_point)

  def _GetBoundingPoints(self, x):
    """Get the lower/upper points that bound x."""
    lower_point = None
    upper_point = self.points[0]
    for point  in self.points[1:]:
      lower_point = upper_point
      upper_point = point
      if x <= upper_point[0]:
        break
    return lower_point, upper_point

  def _Interpolate(self, x, lower_point, upper_point):
    """Interpolate a Y value for x given lower & upper
    bounding points."""
    slope = (float(upper_point[1] - lower_point[1]) /
             (upper_point[0] - lower_point[0]))
    return lower_point[1] + (slope * (x - lower_point[0]))
```

it just complain "invalid syntax" in the line:
    else:

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a closed parenthesis:

```
return self.points[0][1] + (x - self.points[0][0]) * float(self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1] / (self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0])
```

It looks like you mean to have a `)` after `self.points[0][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing parenthesis on this line (the one right before the `else`):

```
return self.points[0][1] + (x - self.points[0][0]) * float(self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1] / (self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0])
```

You have 3 opening parenthesis but only two closing.

I can't tell you the *exact* position to place it because that depends on what you want to do.  However, it most likely will be:

```
return self.points[0][1] + (x - self.points[0][0]) * float(self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1] / (self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0]))
#                                                                                                                                   here--^
```

or:

```
return self.points[0][1] + (x - self.points[0][0]) * float(self.points[1][1] - self.points[0][1]) / (self.points[1][0] - self.points[0][0])
#                                                                                         here--^
```